# BeautifulSoup me hace el conteo 2 veces! porque?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Estoy tratando de crear una lista con todos los numeros (enteros) que salen en la url, pero me genera una lista con 2 listas dentro y los numeros, es decir hace el proceso 2 veces... porque pasa esto?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
import re

# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

#url = input('Enter - ')
html = urlopen("http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.html", context=ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
count=0
lst=[]

for line in soup:
    #lin = soup.rstrip()
    x = re.findall("[0-9]+",str(soup))
    if len(x) == 0:
        continue
    lst.append(x)
    count+=1

print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[['4', '1', '1', '2', '97', '97', '90', '90', '88', '87', '87', '80', '79', '79', '78', '76', '76', '72', '72', '66', '66', '65', '65', '64', '61', '61', '59', '58', '57', '57', '54', '51', '49', '47', '40', '38', '37', '36', '36', '32', '25', '24', '22', '21', '19', '18', '18', '14', '12', '12', '9', '7', '3', '2'], ['4', '1', '1', '2', '97', '97', '90', '90', '88', '87', '87', '80', '79', '79', '78', '76', '76', '72', '72', '66', '66', '65', '65', '64', '61', '61', '59', '58', '57', '57', '54', '51', '49', '47', '40', '38', '37', '36', '36', '32', '25', '24', '22', '21', '19', '18', '18', '14', '12', '12', '9', '7', '3', '2']]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es porque en el re.findall, pusiste como parámetro soup en ves de line, por eso las dos listas. Además de que ese método te devuelve una lista por lo tanto estás insertando una lista dentro de otra, en ese caso vos tenes que usar el método extend en vez de append.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
import re

# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

#url = input('Enter - ')
html = urlopen("http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.html",         context=ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
count=0
lst=[]

for line in soup:
    #lin = soup.rstrip()
    x = re.findall("[0-9]+",str(line))
    if len(x) == 0:
        continue
    lst.extend(x)
    count+=1

print(lst)
```